# Set text color for whole application

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I want to set a particular text color for the whole application. I have defined my style, but dont know whats going wrong..

I have defined my own style:

```
 <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="android:Theme">

   <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>

  </style>
```

For TextAppearance

```
 <style name="TextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/TextColor</item>
 </style>
```

and in manifest set ActionBarTheme

Any help..

Comment: Try modifying the default theme that was set in the manifest and change the textcolor there.

Comment: Or create a custom TextView by overiding the default TextView and set color there.. Then use that view in all layouts

Answer (score 1):

you can use **TextView.getTextColors().getDefaultColor()** for set default text color. Actually I never used this but I think it may be help you.

For style

```
<style name="TextColor">
          <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

Then in layout file

```
<TextView  style="@style/TextColor" />
```

Thanks

Comment: but in this case, I always use to define <TextView  style="@style/TextColor" /> in every layout textview. I want to make this as default for all textview

Comment: Set your default color in your res/values/colors.xml like this
<color name="defaultTextColor">#ffffff</color>
So this color to all your texts
android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"

Comment: Try this way. It may help you
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
     <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonTheme</item>
  </style>
And this is how you can set your Button Theme:

<style name="ButtonTheme" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
And also do this with EditTexts etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use text appearance here.
You can however add this to your theme

```
     <item name="android:editTextColor">#65e4f4</item>
     <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#65e4f4</item>
     <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#65e4f4</item>
     <item name="android:textColorTertiary">#65e4f4</item>
     <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#65e4f4</item>
     <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">#65e4f4</item>
     <item name="android:textColorTertiaryInverse">#65e4f4</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create this item under a style that you are applying to your application in the styles.xml file.

```
        <item name="colorError">@color/orange</item>
```